# Deploying a web.py server

Tags: python, nginx, server, web.py

I have a simple server written in web.py.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

# Unicode
from __future__ import unicode_literals

import sys
reload(sys)
# -----

# Logging
import logging
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)
# -----

# Libs
import web
import json
# -----

urls = ("/", "Index",
        "/endpoint1", "EP1",
        "/endpoint2", "EP2")
app = web.application(urls, globals())

class Index(object):
    def GET(self):
        return "Index"
    def POST(self):
        data = web.data()
        web.header('Content-Type', 'application/json')
        try:
            result = json.loads(data)
        except:
            return "BAD JSON Index"

        logging.info("[Server] Index " + json.dumps(result))
        return "Index POST"

class EP1(object):
    def GET(self):
        return "EP1"
    def POST(self):
        data = web.data()
        web.header('Content-Type', 'application/json')
        try:
            result = json.loads(data)
        except:
            return "BAD JSON EP1"
        logging.info("[Server] EP1 " + json.dumps(result))
        return "EP1 POST"


class EP2(object):
    def GET(self):
        return "EP2"
    def POST(self):
        data = web.data()
        web.header('Content-Type', 'application/json')
        try:
            result = json.loads(data)
        except:
            return "BAD JSON EP2"

        logging.info("[Server] EP2 " + json.dumps(result))
        return "EP2 POST"

if __name__ == "__main__":
    logging.info("[Server] Starting server.")
    web.wsgi.runwsgi = lambda func, addr=None: web.wsgi.runfcgi(func, addr)
    app.run()
```

Before adding web.wsgi, I could run it with `python server.py 0.0.0.0:7331` and it worked, I could access it.

The problem is, it only worked on my machine. Other machines didn't see the server.

I assumed this was due to me not using nginx or apache. So, I followed through [this nginx tutorial](http://webpy.org/cookbook/fastcgi-nginx).

I installed all the requirements, and I am running nginx. I also modified it's configuration, but adding the `location / {}` described in the tutorial. Moreover, I added `listen 7331;` in server.

My nginx configuration looks like this:

```
user www-data;
worker_processes 4;
pid /run/nginx.pid;

events {
    worker_connections 768;
}

http {
    sendfile on;
    tcp_nopush on;
    tcp_nodelay on;
    keepalive_timeout 65;
    types_hash_max_size 2048;

    include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type application/octet-stream;

    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

    gzip on;
    gzip_disable "msie6";

    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
    include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;

        server {

                 listen 7331;
                 location / {
                               fastcgi_param REQUEST_METHOD $request_method;
                               fastcgi_param QUERY_STRING $query_string;
                               fastcgi_param CONTENT_TYPE $content_type;
                               fastcgi_param CONTENT_LENGTH $content_length;
                               fastcgi_param GATEWAY_INTERFACE CGI/1.1;
                               fastcgi_param SERVER_SOFTWARE nginx/$nginx_version;
                               fastcgi_param REMOTE_ADDR $remote_addr;
                               fastcgi_param REMOTE_PORT $remote_port;
                               fastcgi_param SERVER_ADDR $server_addr;
                               fastcgi_param SERVER_PORT 7331;
                               fastcgi_param SERVER_NAME $server_name;
                               fastcgi_param SERVER_PROTOCOL $server_protocol;
                               fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $fastcgi_script_name;
                               fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_script_name;
                               fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9002;
                 }  
        }

}
```

There are a few other lines, but they are commented out, so I removed them.

For `fastcgi_param SERVER_PORT 7331;` I also tried with `$server_port`

Now, I cannot start my server with `python server.py 0.0.0.0:7331` because I get a following error.

```
WSGIServer: missing FastCGI param REQUEST_METHOD required by WSGI!
WSGIServer: missing FastCGI param SERVER_NAME required by WSGI!
WSGIServer: missing FastCGI param SERVER_PORT required by WSGI!
WSGIServer: missing FastCGI param SERVER_PROTOCOL required by WSGI!
Status: 404 Not Found
Content-Type: text/html
```

Starting with the scrip, like this, doesn't work either.

```
spawn-fcgi -d /path/to/www -f /path/to/www/server.py -a 0.0.0.0 -p 7331
```

It says it started correctly, and gives me a PID for the server process. I can find the process with ps aux. However, if I try to connect to `my.external.ip.number:7331/` or `my.external.ip.number:7331/endpoint*` it doesn't work, it just tries to connect for a long time and in the end fails.

---

So, now that I described the problem, my questions are:

1. How can I make other machines see my server?
2. Is it necessary to use nginx or apache or another server service to make my server available to other machines?
3. If the answer to number 2 is "Yes", can you please tell me why? Why does my server need another server to make it available. What exactly is nginx or apache doing to make my server visible to other machines?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: What do you mean by "my.external.ip.number"? Regardless, the answer to #2 is "No,", and your question is about network configuration, not about programming. Voting to close and redirect to http://serverfault.com/

Comment: What I mean by "my.external.ip.number" is the IP I get by running the command ip addr show eth0 | grep inet | awk '{ print $2; }' | sed 's/\/.*$//'
You are right, this is more of a networking problem than a programming one. I was under the impression I was running the server incorrectly, but the same code, run in the same way, creates a visible server on another machine. Although I disabled my firewall and explicitly allow 7331 in iptables, I still cannot reach the server if I run it on the initial machine.

Comment: I imagine the folks at one of our sister sites, http://serverfault.com or http://superuser.com, will be able to figure it out quickly.